# Rank checker tool for keywords

Tags: keyword

Can anyone suggest the rank checking tool which checks around 20 keywords for an url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox Rank Checker](http://www.seobook.com/announcing-firefox-rank-checker) is a very reliable tool, which i use all the time, has a limitation of 20 keywords though, but that matches your criteria

Answer (score 2):

Try [ExactFactor](http://www.exactfactor.com/), with the free account you can check the rankings of 25 keywords on google, yahoo and bing search engines.